# Analytic solutions of an equation

Tags: functional-analysis, roots

I am trying to find analytic solutions of this equation for $x$ with parameter $a$ ($x>0, a>0$):

$$(\log(ax))^2\frac{x}{(x+1)^2}+2\log(ax)\frac{1}{x+1}+2\log\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)-2\log(1+a)=0$$

From simulations I see that the equation has two solutions. One is easy to find (just by plugging in)
$$x_1=\frac{1}{a}$$
I'm unable to find the second one. Is their a closed-form solution for $x_2$?

Comment: It might not be possible to find a closed form solution but there might be a useful approximation to it.  Is $a$ large, small, ...?

Comment: @AntonioVargas $a$ is typically between $0.5<a<2$. I know that in case of $a=1$, then there is only one solution: $x=\frac{1}{a}=1$.